# Should a .Net protocol-less URI showing as relative?

Tags: c#, .net, url, uri

All,

In HTML, it is my understanding that a url that starts // (e.g. //www.google.com) refers to a protocol-less url that should be requested in the same scheme as that in which the page was served.

However, the following c# code fails

```
var uri = new Uri("//www.google.com", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Assert.IsTrue(uri.IsAbsoluteUri);
```

Am I missing something here? At the moment I am rolling my own regex to find out if a URI is absolute:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(url, @"^(https?:)?//")
```

Comment: It's actually called a protocol-_relative_ URL.

Comment: Strictly, it's not relative to the URI of the entity served, but to the base URI. That does default to the URI of the entity you get the relative URI reference in, but `xml:base`, HTML's `<base/>` element and other mechanism can override that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not absolute.  It's relative to whether the URL is accessed from a source that is served over HTTP, HTTPS, or something else.

Comment: I guess you and @SLaks are right - I didn't really appreciate that not having a scheme made the URI absolute.

Comment: @JonBates if it doesn't mean anything outside of the context of another URI, then it can't be absolute.